# Django: simple_tag not rendering simple string

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to create dynamic menus list under one mega menu.The menus will be fetched from database.I am using Django simeple_tag feature to achieve this but some how does not render the simple test string which I am giving although I want to render HTML tags at the end.Here is my code,

**my_app/home/templatetags/menus.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(name='downloadable_menus')
def downloadable_menus(a):
    """
    Generate the downloadable menus under the free resources mega menu
    """
    return 'Hello'
```

**This is how I am using in template.**

```
{% load menus %}

<div class="content">
    <ul class="menu-col">
                                             
       {{ downloadable_menus }}
                                                                              
     </ul>
 </div>
```

So the above code should display the "Hello" string in the menu but it is not.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to use a template tag such as that is:

```
{% downloadable_menus %}
```

Double curly brackets (`{{ something }}`) are for variables. The reason nothing is rendered will be because there is no variable called `downloadable_menus` so django ignores it (the default setting).

Comment: Ohh...noob mistake..Thanks though.